# Android app SQLite addButtonClicked IllegalStateException

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi im trying to create a simple SQLite database in a fragment in which an individual can store memos. there is no error obvious errors on the app but once a user tries to add anything and clicks the add button I receive the following error. If anyone knows where I am going wrong it would be much appreciated

> 03-29 11:45:08.781 6065-6065/com.test.test.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.test.test.app, PID: 6065
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method
>   addButtonClicked(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for
>   android:onClick attribute defined on view class
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'addButton'

MemoFragment.java

```
package com.teat.test.app;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
  * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
  */
public class MemoFragment extends Fragment {

EditText Input;
TextView LyricText;
MyDBHandler dbHandler;
Button addButtonClicked;
Button deleteButtonClicked;

public MemoFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_memo, container, false);

    Input = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.Input);
    LyricText = (TextView) v.findViewById (R.id.LyricText);
    dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(getActivity() ,null, null, 1);
    printDatabase ();
    return v;
}
//add lyric to database
    public void addButtonClicked(View view){
    Lyrics lyrics = new Lyrics(Input.getText().toString());
        dbHandler.addLyric(lyrics);
    printDatabase();
}

//delete items
public void deleteButtonClicked(View view){
    String inputtext = Input.getText().toString();
    dbHandler.deleteLyrics(inputtext);
    printDatabase();


}

public void printDatabase(){
    String dbString = dbHandler.databaseToString();
    LyricText.setText(dbString);
    Input.setText("");
}

}
```

fragment_memo.xml

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Input"
    android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
    android:width="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add"
    android:id="@+id/addButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Input"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Input"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Input"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:onClick="addButtonClicked" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Delete"
    android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/addButton"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Input"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Input"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:onClick="deleteButtonClicked" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/LyricText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/deleteButton"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/addButton"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/addButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="102dp" />
```

Comment: button click method added via xml  not work in case of fragments. Add onClick code in your java file instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the app expects to find `addButtonClicked` and `deleteButtonClicked` methods in your `Activity`, not in the `MemoFragment`.

Either move these methods to the Activity class or set the listeners inside the MemoFragment and remove `android:onClick="..."` from your layout.

Comment: I had an idea that it couldn't find the buttons due to them showing as never used. By any chance would you know how I could change it to be expecting in `MemoFragment`

Comment: I highly doubt that it's possible.

Comment: Thank you. would I need to implement `Input` over aswell. and do you know of any examples of how I can implement the button into the java instead of XML

Comment: obtain a reference to the button and set a click listener on it ->
`Button b = (Button ) v.findViewById(R.id.addButton); b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)    {
        //your code goes here
    } 
});`